# how can get content of Displayfor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

how can you get content of Displayfor in javascript? I wanna put the content of Displayfor to  lable1.

```
<span id="lable1">
    @Html.DisplayFor(z => z.name, new { @id = "nm" })
</span>

<script>
    document.getElementById('lable1').innerHTML = ////???
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that? The content is already in the span. What's the purpose of the javascript in this case?

Comment: i have a textbox and  a button . i want to when i change textbox's content , DisplayFor will change too . i mean the content of textbox will show in DisplayFor . and i thought put DisplayFor in a span . is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the jquery way of doing that is

```
$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
    $('#label1').text($('.txtField').val());
});
```

the display for just renders the value without tags so you are correct in needing to select on the span id.  I believe you can set the content of a span with .text, may need to set it with .html